DnSpy material editing/adding
I am trying to change a material of a game object in dnSpy, however I am not sure where the materials would be. I have looked in assembly-csharp.dll.
Also, if or when I can find the materials, is it possible to edit them to my own in dnSpy? If so how?

dnSpy is probably not the right tool for this job. assemly-csharp.dll will contain the IL code for the game's C# scripts, not the data for assets like the materials and shaders. Those will more likely be in the .assets/.resource files in the "gameName_Data" folder. These are binary files not suitable for manual editing, and I don't think Unity has documented the file format. You can find asset ripping tools to unpack them, but since such tools can be used to steal assets from a game, you may find that game developers are not eager to coach you on how to use them.

It may be worth reaching out to the creator of this game and asking them if they could add modding support for the kind of asset change you have in mind. Some developers are very pro-modding and will provide tools and assistance to help their community customize the game.
